# xsl fo fo block visibility not working

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

If I set the attribute `visibility="hidden"` it has no effect on the element `fo:block`.

```
<fo:block visibility="hidden">Download:</fo:block>
```

It would be show in the document.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Most FO engines do not support visibility. Do you want it just hidden but space retained or do you want it completely removed and space associated collapsed?

Comment: thanks. i want that is simply hidden, that mean if space reprecented it is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If visibility is not supported by your FO engine, you could use

```
<fo:block color="white">
```

(or whatever color matches the background color). If you use white and the output will be printed by a full-color printer, you may have to tweak the PDF so you don't waste money printing the white text.

With this method, the text will still be in the PDF, and may possibly be extractable.
If you want to avoid that, you could create a custom font where every character is rendered as a space. Then specify your block to use this font.

Comment: If you are changing the fo, why not leave the actual words out. I guess I don't understand.